# Qt6.3 QML FastBlur

Tags: qt, qml

I try the FastBlur with doc.
Why I always got a purple image?
Take off the FastBlur the image is right.

```
import QtQuick
import Qt5Compat.GraphicalEffects
Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")


    Image {
        id: icon
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: 132
        height: 105
        source: "file:////Users/otis.lin/Desktop/test.png"

        FastBlur {
            anchors.fill: icon
            source: icon
            radius: 64
        }
    }
}
```

**purple image:**

[image: purple image]

---

Update code here, this is work for me.

```
    Image {
        id: img
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: "file:////Users/otis.lin/Desktop/test.png"
        sourceSize: Qt.size(parent.width, parent.height)
        smooth: true

    }
    FastBlur{
        id: blur
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: img
        radius: 32
    }
```

Comment: probably `FastBlur` shouldn't be a child of the `Image` but sibling

Comment: your question is like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68863137/9484913 , and that answer will fix it.

Comment: thanks guys,  layer.effect: ShaderEffect not working, still have a purple image, I tried some methods about the @Parisa.H.R 
reply stackoverflow.com/a/68863137/9484913 , code update under my question.